# Groovy and Grail plugin is missing in Netbeans IDE 9

Tags: grails, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-9

This is the first time I am trying with Grails. 
I followed the same post "[Why I can't create new grails application in Netbeans 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424377/why-i-cant-create-new-grails-application-in-netbeans-8-2/50429300#50429300)"
I installed Netbeans 9 beta version from https://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip

But for me, Groovy/Grails plugin is not available in the plugin window. How to get grail plugin in my case? [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use Grails with NetBeans 9.0 you must do the following:

1. Make the **Groovy and Grails** plugin available.
2. Install the **Groovy and Grails** plugin.
3. Configure **Grails**.
4. Create a Grails project.

Here are the details:

Step 1:
To make the plugin available:

- **Tools > Plugins >** click the **Settings** tab, then click the **Add** button.
- In the **Update Center Customizer** dialog:

  - Enter some descriptive value in the **Name** field, such as: *NetBeans 8.2 Plugins*
  - Enter https://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz in the **URL** field, and click **OK**.

    [image: Grails1]

Step 2: 
To install the plugin:

- In the **Available Plugins** tab select and check the entry for the **Groovy and Grails** plugin.
- Click the **Install** button to install the plugin, then restart NetBeans.

  [image: Grails2]

Step 3:
To configure Grails:

- **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous >** select the newly added **Groovy** tab.
- Enter the location of your Grails installation in the **Grails Home** field, and click **OK**.
  [image: Grails3]

Step 4:
To create a Grails project:

- **File > New Project >** select **Groovy** from the **Categories** list.
- Select **Grails Application** from the **Projects** list, click **Next >** and complete the wizard to create your Grails project.
  [image: Grails4]

Comment: As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326975/unable-to-connect-to-the-netbeans-distribution-because-of-zero-sized-file the URL should start with https://

Comment: @RadimBača Thanks. I have updated the _Update Center Customizer_ URL to use _https_ instead of _http_. Both URLs worked for me, but of course using _https_ is preferable.

Comment: If you are using Netbeans 11 or 12, then you need to uncheck Netbeans Distribution on Settings tab for 11 or 12 version. So that it should pick plugin from 8.2 distribution.