# Is Netbeans 14 still not supporting Grails project?

Tags: grails, netbeans

Netbeans 8 works quite well with Grails. I can click New Project to create a new Grails project. Netbeans 8 can show the project with Domain, Controller, Views folders on the left nicely.  I can even debug the project with breakpoint.  Netbeans 8 only works well with Grails 2.  But at lease it can show the project folder structures nicely with newer versions of Grails like 4 and 5.

Netbeans 14 is missing all of these with/without the default Groovy plugin.  It can't even open a simple Helloworld Grails project I create using the `grails create-app helloworld` command.

I googled Netbeans and Grails but the posts were quite outdated from many years ago. They said to use the Netbeans 8 Groovy plugin.

Is there any updated way to setup Netbeans 14 to work with Grails?

I attached 2 pictures.  One is how it looks with 14.  The other is how it looks with 8.

[image: Netbeans 8]

[image: Netbeans 14]

Comment: You're using an IDE released 11 days ago.  There might still be some issues.  Why do you need v14?

Comment: I have tried 9 to 13.  None of them works with Grails.  I am hoping 14 will work with Grails but it doesn't.  I am still using 8 and it is very old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the answer to your question is that Netbeans 14 does not support Grails. It's tough to prove a negative, but there is very strong circumstantial evidence of that being the case:

- If you go to the [homepage for Apache NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/) there is a **Plugins** menu entry,and clicking that [yields a list of the 62 available plugins](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/). If you search that list list for *"Grails"* nothing is returned, so there is no "official" plugin for Grails.
- Within NetBeans 14, if you select **Tools > Plugins** and search the **Installed** and **Available Plugins** tabs for *"Grails"*, nothing is returned.
- If you review [the *"What's Changed"* entries for NetBeans 14](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/releases/tag/14) there is no mention of Grails.
- Note [this comment from GeertJan Wielenga, Release Manager for Apache NetBeans](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/1077#issuecomment-455861063) in 2019 (emphasis mine): *"I would recommend to keep the name at Groovy, because otherwise **when we re-add support for Grails**, we’ll need to call it ‘Groovy, Gradle, and Grails’. And anyway both Gradle and Grails derive from Groovy, so keeping the name Groovy makes sense."*

Notes:

- For some releases since NetBeans 8.2 it has been possible to add Grails support using the old 8.2 plugin (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54995849/2985643)), but the approaches were brittle, and did not offer any functionality beyond that available in NetBeans 8.2. I suppose you could try a similar workaround to get Grails running on NetBeans 14, as described in SO answers for other NetBeans releases, but stability might be an issue.
- For what it's worth, [Intellij IDEA provides a Grails plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18504-grails), though I haven't tried it.
- Finally, Grails not working in NetBeans 14 should not be viewed as a NetBeans issue. Instead, it's a third-party plugin issue, and as far as I know there has been no development on the 8.2 plugin you are currently using for years. (That said, it would be helpful if the NetBeans documentation for each release formally stated any new functionality, and any functionality that was no longer supported, or no longer worked.)

Comment: The IntelliJ Grails plugin is excellent and I can recommend it without reservation if moving to that IDE is an option for you.  It really only lacks a couple features (like GSP support), but even those features are available if you pay for their "Ultimate" edition IDE.